# Date compare without time

Tags: java, date-comparison

I realise this is a question asked many times, but I have sifted through and can't seem to find an answer that would assist me completely. I'd start with saying that I can't use Joda.

I am making a change to a program that requires me to compare a user input date (From Date) with a date from a column.

The request can't be done using SQL as the filter for the date check on this column has to be ran after the results are returned.

The code is checking an entry on the table, making a comparison between the "From Date" and the field entry, and then it will display that row of data dependent on whether the boolean returns a true or false.

All the code is working fine apart from one section. It checks if the date on the table is more than or equal to the "From Date".

Example:

> The user enters the date 13/04/2015.
>
> The program SHOULD return all rows with the date field that is
>   13/04/2015 or later.
>
> The program actually returns all dates that are 1 day after this date.
>   i.e. anything that is 14/04/2015 and onwards.

My code for the check on this section is:

```
private boolean checkArngdDateCriteria(OrderBean singleOrderBean) {
    if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()!= null || getSearchArngdToDate().getValue()!= null) {
        Date checkArngdToDate = (Date)getSearchArngdToDate().getValue();
        Date checkArngdFromDate = (Date)getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue();

        if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()!= null && getSearchArngdToDate().getValue()== null && singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD()!= null) {
            if (singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD().after(checkArngdFromDate) || singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD().equals(checkArngdFromDate)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

> EDIT:
>
> ```
> //This retrieves the date from the results table
> singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD()
>
> //This retrieves the value from the user input field (retrieved as Object)
> getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()
> ```

Does anybody know a bit of code that would make it so the `From Date` would be treated as equal or less than the table date if they were both 13/04/2015?

Comment: Can't fully understand what you are asking here. However sometimes it's enough to replace `after()` with `!before()`

Comment: I've tried that. I am trying to have it so that when I check a date range on the columns, that the from date is included in the list. Currently when the from date is a particular date (Example: 16/09/2015) then only the dates AFTER that date are included. I need the specific date to be included in the results.

Comment: So can you please improve your question and attach a test case? Remove everything except the minimal runnable code you need to fix

Comment: That code is the section I need to fix. I've already excluded any code that doesn't apply to this problem. When I enter a date into the UI Input box and click apply, the results don't include rows that have a date matching the date that the user inputs (From Date). Because the check has to be done after the results are retrieved from multiple tables, I can't use SQL to filter it out.

Comment: I can't understand why the rows with matching dates aren't being retrieved when I have it checking for dates that are equal to or after the "From Date"

Comment: Can you just check what is date Object value 'Date checkArngdFromDate' while executing this code !!

Comment: Casting to date like this looks dodgy to me, what kind of value are you casting from? `Date checkArngdFromDate = (Date)getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue();`. I would use a SimpleDateFormat to parse what is probably a String from a text field?

Comment: It's getting the value from a UI Input field that is being treated as an Object, not a String. I'm unsure what the date Object value is, as my VM host server is currently unavailable. I was trying to get some example results to display, but I can't yet.

Comment: @Raffaele When I first used the `!before()` command, I wrote it incorrectly as `singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD().!before(checkArngdFromDate)`. I'm new to this and I wrote it wrong, I've learnt a great deal from this program change. After using the command correctly, combined with some code to zero the time portion, it now works.

Comment: @MiteshParmar It was coming through without a time portion that I was able to compare to. Fixed this by setting the time portion to 00:00:00. Thank you for that suggestion. It helped me realise why some of the code wasn't working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date class includes time fields (and various other fields). You are comparing for 'after' or 'equals'. However, 'equals' is not doing what you think it's doing. It's not just comparing dates. It will only return `true` if *all* fields are equal. The easiest way to fix it is, instead of doing 'after or equals', do 'not before'.

```
        if (!singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD().before(checkArngdFromDate)) {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: That wasn't working for me. I had to combine it with some code to add a time portion to the value retrieved from the user input and then set the time portion to zero.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody wondering, the final code ended up as:

```
private boolean checkArngdDateCriteria(OrderBean singleOrderBean) {
    if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()!= null || getSearchArngdToDate().getValue()!= null) {
        Date checkArngdFromDate = (Date)getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue();
        Date checkArngdToDate = (Date)getSearchArngdToDate().getValue();

        if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()!= null) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(checkArngdFromDate);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            checkArngdFromDate = cal.getTime();
        }

        if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()!= null && getSearchArngdToDate().getValue()== null && singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD()!= null) {
            if (!singleOrderBean.getOrdStatD().before(checkArngdFromDate)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I had to put the Calendar section inside an `if statement` so that it wouldn't interfere with a later `if statement` that checks `if (getSearchArngdFromDate().getValue()== null && ...)`

Comment: Got a tip/trick from a colleague. Another way to do it would be to parse the date to 'yyyyMMdd' format in to an integer. Could then use the int to compare the dates with ease. Would have to be in the yyyyMMdd format to ensure the dates values can be compared correctly.